# How to determine the "orientation" of a basis within a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

I trying to check if a supplied set of orthogonal vectors {u<sub>1</sub>,...,u<sub>n</sub>} could have been found by applying the Gram-Schmidt process to a known set of vectors {v<sub>1</sub>,...,v<sub>n</sub>}.

Checking whether the orthogonal vectors span the correct subspace can be done by comparing the RREF of V<sup>T</sup> to the RREF of U<sup>T</sup>; however, this alone is not sufficient to say that the vectors could have been found from Gram-Schmidt. Since the vectors can be chosen in n! different orders, it appears that there are n! valid "orientations" of the vectors.

A simple example would involve two vectors, v={[1 2], [4 2]}, in R<sup>2</sup>.

Letting u<sub>1</sub>=[1 2], then u<sub>2</sub>=v<sub>2</sub>-1.6u<sub>1</sub>=[2.4 -1.2]. }

These vectors can be described by their angle with the x-axis (as I do no care about the "negative" of the correct orientation).

This can be repeated using v<sub>2</sub> for u<sub>1</sub> to find a different angle with the x-axis. In this example, I want a logical expression that returns true if the supplied vectors u<sub>i</sub> form one of these two angles with the x-axis.

My questions is two-fold. First, is there a way to describe the orientation of a basis within a subspace? Second, is there a way to determine the n! valid orientations from the original set of v<sub>i</sub>?

It is also important to note that I do not have access to recursion of any kind. All logical expressions need to be able to be implemented using functions like "MergeColumns", "Transpose", "Determinant", "RREF", "Product", and similarly simple operations.

The application is for an answer-judging algorithm (online learning), and the student is asked to use the Gram-Schmidt process. The current algorithm only checks to determine if the correct subspace is spanned and if the vectors are orthogonal. So other solutions, that are in the same spirit, would also be appreciated.

Comment: Your use of the word orientation is most non-standard! A finite-dimensional vector space has two orientations, and one distinguishes between them by the sign of the determinant.

Comment: I put some instances of "orientation" in quotes. I am trying to refer to the orientation of the basis within the vector space, not the orientation of the vector space itself. I believe when I reference the "negative" of the correct orientation, I am referring to the corresponding solution in the vector space with opposite orientation.